# Launching app outside of sender using Intent Filter

Tags: java, android, intentfilter

So I'm trying to capture geo addresses from outside my app, and I've set up the code that follows in my manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="0">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

that works great, when I click a postal address or lat/lng pair in the browser, it has my app in the picker that pops up.

The issue I have is that when selecting my app from said popup picker, it starts the Intent ***in the browser.*** I want to actually start my app outside of the browser, like what the Google Maps app does, as monopolizing the browser wouldn't be a very nice thing to do to my users.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, and apologies if this is already a question, I couldn't find something similar searching around.

Comment: "The issue I have is that when selecting my app from said popup picker, it starts the Intent in the browser" -- then you are causing the browser to appear, either in the rest of your `<activity>` element, or in your Java code.

Comment: nowhere in my app is the browser referenced or used. Is there something special that must be done for intent filters in your main activity?